# Show that $AP=AQ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ and $E, D$ on $[AB]$ and $[AC]$ s.t. $BEDC$ is inscribable. Let $P\in [BD], Q\in [CE]$ s.t. $AEPC$ and $ADQB$ are also inscribable. Show that $AP=AQ$.

I draw the points and I considered $R$, the point of intersections of the two circles, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Comment: I did not check whether your approach leads to the required proof or not. But, I know that $\measuredangle APR \ne \measuredangle AEC$ and  $\measuredangle AQR \ne \measuredangle ADP$. You better check yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\angle ABD = \angle EBD = \angle ECD = \angle ACE \Rightarrow$ $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle ACE \Rightarrow$ $\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{AE}{AC} \Rightarrow$ $AD\cdot AC=AB\cdot AE$

$\angle EPA = \angle ECA = \angle ECD = \angle EBD = \angle PBA \Rightarrow$ $\triangle EPA \sim \triangle PBA \Rightarrow$ $\frac{AE}{AP}=\frac{AP}{AB}\Rightarrow$ $AP^2=AB\cdot AE$

In the same way: $AQ^2 = AC\cdot AD$

Then $AP^2 = AB\cdot AE = AC\cdot AD = AQ^2$, $AP =AQ$

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

$\angle AQR\neq\angle ADP$ as mentioned in comment.I made two drawings, one isosceles. These points are noticeable:

1- The measure of the sides and angles of isosceles triangle  APQ does not vary with the type of triangle.

2- It can be assumed as a kind of affine transformation. Because base of triangle is fixed and the location of vertex A alters. It is like moving a triangle APQ relative to the base of ABC to construct three circles with certain measures of diameter.

I can not add picture because of problem with site. I wanted to send Drawing by e-mail I did not have your address.